# Clearing a row based on the state of the first element

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, matrix

There is a 3d array:

Input:

```
    [[[0,2,3,4]
    [4,2,3,4]
    [6,2,3,4]]
    [[2,2,3,4]
    [3,2,3,4]
    [2,2,3,4]]]
```

How can I make a numpy array look like this?

```
rule: if array[:,:,0] < 3
```

Output:

```
    [[[0,0,0,0]
    [4,2,3,4]
    [6,2,3,4]]
    [[0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
a[a[:,: ,0] <= 3, :] = 0
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [4, 2, 3, 4],
        [6, 2, 3, 4]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

*NOTE:* I've assumed you wanna turn rows to 0 where the value is `<` or `=` to `3`. Change the condition if required.

Comment: Exactly. Thank you very much. I'm just learning numpy and haven't figured out the syntax yet

Comment: @ArkadiyEpanov No problem!!.. Happy coding : )